# What should be put into the project, folder and package

Tags: java, eclipse, naming-conventions

I am a beginner to Java. I am using Eclipse now.
What makes me confused is that I am not clear with the dogma of putting files into a project, a folder and a package. If I build a new class, should I put it into the original package or create a new package or new folder or even new project and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This completely depends on application you are developing. If you are developing a large application with many modules in it you should create different projects, linked to each other.

But you say you are beginner, so the answer to your question would be: you should always have your classes classified in different package. The classification is entirely your choice - you can even classify alphabetically if you are comfortable with it. I normally classify them according to their functionalities, like all my Controller classes will be in one package, so are my Bean Classes, Listeners, Constants, Builders, utils, parsers, comparators, models, renderers and so on.

[This Java Practices article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=205) would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

### Project Structure

I would strongly advise you to follow Maven conventions for the structure : http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html
They are the result of many years of experience.

However, designing such a structure is always a matter of compromise between extensibility and simplicity. The more you foresee, the more that will be complex to maintain, but the more you will get back your investment if it grow fast.

To be pragmatic, and even I'm not really convinced (because my job is to anticipate ;)), try KISS philosophy : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle.

### Package Structure

As Amandeep Jiddewar said, packages must represents their own functionnality.
At least, they have to be reverse domain like : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html. For instance, stackoverflow API should be :  com.stackoverflow.*

And maybe, in the first time, they diveded it into MVC pattern

- com.stackoverflow.controler
- com.stackoverflow.model
- com.stackoverflow.view

and so on...

And when the project was mature ... or has grown too much, they splitted it into a war for presentation layer, and jar(s) for service layer ...

### Further considerations

There is no specifi rule. As I said, you will always have to deal with compromise. Only experience will give you the hability to know when to change your configuration.

Look around Stack Overflow for more ideas : [naming-conventions](/questions/tagged/naming-conventions)